# Are 'tiles' that are part of the coastline counted when scoring?

Tags: carcassonne-new-world

In *Carcassonne: New World*, the game doesn't start with a single start tile but with a board representing a coastline, that of the East Coast of the USA. It is divided by lines to mimic tiles, against which the players' tiles are placed. When scoring a feature that contains these starting 'tiles', are these counted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again, US rules to the rescue. My Dutch rules do not include these examples, but in the scoring examples in [the rules of the US version](http://riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_262_gameRules.pdf), one of the examples shows a trail (this would be a road in regular Carcassonne) that consists of two tiles and two tile-sized sections of the starting board. The score is calculated using all four tiles.